# ruby on rails mysql returns no result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

when i get data of Book, it doesn't return values

here is list.html.erb file

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>publish</th>
            <th>published</th>
    </tr>
<%= "asdf" %>
<% @books.each do |book| %>
<%= "asdf" %>
    <tr>
            <td><%= book.isbn %></td>
            <td><%= book.title%></td>
            <td><%= book.price%></td>
            <td><%= book.publish%></td>
            <td><%= book.published%></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and, here is fm_controller.rb

```
    ...
    def list
            @books = Book.all
            @booksCount = Book.count
            puts @books
            puts @booksCount

    end
end
```

if you need more information, i'll update soon. help me...

(edit, more information)
server log prints like this

```
Started GET "/fm/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-16 06:59:48 -0700
Processing by FmController#list as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `books`
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `books`.* FROM `books`
  0
Rendering fm/list.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered fm/list.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 13.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

@bookCount prints 0 but mysql table have 1 row. here is my query result

```
select * from book;

+------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
| isbn | title | price | publish | published |
+------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
| 1111 | asdf  |  1233 | sasdf   | asdf      |
+------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have any data in books table

Comment: can you please post the result for `Book.count`

Comment: Book.count returns 0. but that table has 1 row... why this happens?(i updated my question)

Comment: Looks like you have violated some naming conventions. For a Book model table name should be books.Can you please share Book model and migration file for create table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM books` returns nil
but `SELECT * from book` returns 1 object.
Make your table name books.
`Book.all` fetches records from books table and not book table.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the tick near the answer and upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow near the answer.